# Can I complete the quest "Paarthurnax" after the main quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Blades gave me the *Paarthurnax* quest, but I decided to hold off until I finished the main quest line:

> Once Alduin is defeated, it seems that Paarthurnax took over or something, he has flown away. I can't find him anywhere.

The Blades won't speak to me until I complete the quest: is there any way around this? Or is it too late?

Comment: this game has to be quite buggy then because i've completed the main quest and killed alduin and talked to paarthunax about the blades wanting him dead but he just says they are right about wanting him dead, and i tried stabbing him until he's health "dropped to zero" but there he stays at the wall. I can't kill him anymore :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fast travel around a bit and then back to the Throat of the World, he should be hangin out on top of the dragon wall eventually ready to get stabbed.

Comment: I can confirm JLoveSK's response. After completing the main quest line, he does fly off to unite the dragons under his rule. I guess he gets bored of that real quick. He's perched on top of the Throat of the World, after fast traveling to the Sky Haven Temple and back.

Comment: Ah nice, did not know that. It's likely it's just time-based, sped up by the fast traveling.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can still kill Paarthurnax after the main quest in completed. In my game it is the only way to make Graybeards appear again, as after the main quest they vanished from the world... Well, just leave Throat of the World and return after few hours. The dragon will be there, as usual, to chat him up for a blessing or slay him.

Comment: I came across this thread after defeating Alduin. To answer Dovahkiin's question, I found the Graybeards in my game with Paarthurnax still alive. It was glitchy and I found them by walking around the courtyard until Arngeir appeared. When I was talking to him, the rest of them appeared behind him.

Comment: They don't disappear. I found them sitting in the chamber where you negotiate a truce.