# I have killed Paarthurnax until his health was gone

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have done this over and over but he keeps coming back to life. So how do I get past this and talk to him/kill him?

Comment: I believe he is essential to another quest and you must finish that quest before he becomes non essential; and killable. (seems to be a glitch/bug from what i read around the web)

Comment: Okay. Thanks. What is the other quest that I have to beat first? Do you know?

Comment: Just going to leave a link to this http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98930/paarthurnax-wont-die?rq=1 It doesn't exactly answer everything but it seems to involve the main quest line

Answer (score 4):

[Paarthurnax](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Paarthurnax_(dragon)) is marked as plot-essential until a certain point in the game. If you have not reached that point, you won't be able to kill him... he'll just fall to his knees (or do the dragon equivalent thereof) and then regenerate.

You can disable him, or remove his essential flag, via the console on the PC. This will let you kill him, but it will probably also break subsequent quest progression.

A better option is to wait until the [appropriate point in the story](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Paarthurnax_(quest)) (basically after you capture and interrogate Odahviing), and kill him then.